# Is there a module similar to the Tiered Taxonomy Block module for Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I have two taxonomies (*tags*, and *group*), and one content type (*article*). I want to show tags which have content in page of group/123.

I found [Tiered Taxonomy Block](http://drupal.org/project/tiered_taxonomy_block) which has similar functionality, but it is only for Drupal 6, at the moment.

What is a similar module for Drupal 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if there is a better solution but this can now be done in a round about way with views.

- Create a term view.
- Add a required relationship to its parent term.
- add a required relationship to node.
- add term title for both term and parent term relationship and term count.

You'll have to display the hierarchy at the theme level unless you want to use group headers.